# "Invalid Credentials" after authorizing app on Facebook (using Devise, omniauth :facebook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

I've followed the instructions on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) for logging in with a Facebook account.

It works, mostly.

The problem is, I will log in (`user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)`), which brings me to Facebook where I click the "authorize" button. Then I'm redirected to my app, like I should be, but instead of hitting my callback function, I hit the same page with an error in `flash[:notice]` ("Could not authorize you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials".") and on the backend I see:

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : {"error":{"message":"Code was invalid or expired. Session is invalid. This could be because the application was uninstalled after the session was created.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

After which I get pointed to `Started GET "/accounts/auth/facebook/callback?code=XXX`, but instead of processing in that action (`facebook`), it gets sent to `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure`.

BUT, curiously, when I see which apps I've authorized with my Facebook account, my app is there. And the next time I click the login link, I get immediately authorized (don't get redirected to FB), and logged in by my `facebook` action, no problem.

Any ideas why this is happening, or tips for debugging? They'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: my [omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb](https://gist.github.com/4356065)

Comment: Show us how you are defining the facebook key/id and secret in your app. In a devise.rb file? In an omniauth.rb file? Using ENV variables? Directly in the file?

Comment: It's in the `devise.rb` initialize, as described in the tutorial. As I said, the app is in fact being authorized (it shows up in my list of authorized apps on Facebook, and the next time I click a `user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)` link, the `facebook` callback DOES get called. Terribly frustrating.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Frustrating indeed. What are the settings of your facebook app? In development you should only have to set your Site URL to `http://localhost:3000/` . And how are you defining your routes? `/accounts/auth/facebook/callback?code=XXX` seems a strange url callback. Shouldn't it be `/users/auth/facebook/callback` ?

Comment: The site URL is set to the ip of my VM, so it's not localhost, but it does indeed work (as when I sign in the second time, it redirects me to my site correctly), and the callback routes work as well (as it does hit the callback—we have `accounts`instead of `users` on the app). It all appears to be working, except for what happens after I FIRST authorize the app. People with similar problems (found a few, I think…) haven't been able to find help, either. I may have to just make a simple test case, and work back from there…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that Facebook wasn't working. I logged in fine this morning, having changed no code. Spectacular.

Let this be a lesson to you: sometimes, it's not you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/419168608133421?browse=search_50c9f80c2dcb35786620246

I must say, we use Devise and Facebook oAuth and I have never seen this in our app. Could you post a code snippet of you OmniauthCallbacksController?

Comment: I saw the above link, but I think it's different? It doesn't appear as though the app is getting authorized? I'll post the full code of the callback controller above (in a gist)